$[2x]=[x]+[x+\frac12]$
By definintion, $[x]\le x <[x]+1 \\
[x+\frac12] \leq x+\frac12<[x+\frac12]+1$
Take $m=[x] + [x+\frac12]$ and the two equations above:$$m-0.5\le 2x<m+1.5$$If $2x$ lies in $(m-0.5,m)$, then its floor function will be $m-1$, which is in contradiction with the prove statement. What is the catch here?

Try plugging $m$ in again, but more carefully.

As a rule, use fractions for rational values rather than decimals. Your reader here is forced to read 1/2 in two different ways.

Noe that. if ${x}$ is the fractional part of $x,$ then $\frac12\leq {x}+{x+1/2}<\frac32.$ The range isn't two. it is one.

Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see meta.

So your range is  bigger than the actual range of values.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4135472/42969 for some correct proofs, and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/184361/42969 for a generalization.

This question is similar to: Floor function properties: $[2x] = [x] + [ x + \frac12 ]$ and $[nx] = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} [ x + \frac{k}{n} ]$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using Approach $0$: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5B2x%5D%3D%5Bx%5D%2B%5Bx%2B%5Cfrac12%5D%24&p=1

"If 2x lies in (m−0.5,m)"  Why would you think that is possible?  As $m$ is dependent upon $[x]$ it is quite possible but $[x]+[x+\frac 12] -\frac 12 < 2x < [x]+[x+\frac 12]$ is an impossibility.  $m$ is not a constant that we can place a variable $x$ around.

If $\{u\}=u-\lfloor u\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $u$, then:
$$ \begin{align} 
m& = x-\{x\}+(x+1/2)-\{x+1/2\}\\&=2x+\frac12- \{x\}-\{x+1/2\}. \end{align}$$
Now, notices that $\frac{1}{2}\leq\{x\}+\{x+1/2\}<\frac{3}2.$
So, this means $$m\leq 2x< m+1.$$
Your inequality is correct, but it specifies a range that is not possible. $2x$ is never in $[m-1/2,m).$

Just because we know $\sin^2 x,\cos^2x\in[0,1],$ we can conclude that $0\leq \sin^2x +\cos^2 x\leq 2.$ But that isn't the tightest we can make since the value in the midde is always $1$ Knowing the tightest bounds for an expression can be hard sometimes.

How did you get the first equation?

Sorry, the second set of ${\cdot}$ were missing. @awkalan

Also, your second inequality is wrong. It should be $0\le ...<\frac 32$

@awkalan No, there you are wrong, one of ${x}$ or ${x+1/2}$ is always $\geq 1/2.$ That requires proof, of course, but it is true.

The catch is that this cannot happen.  When you added the inequalities, you got an interval of length 2 for where $2x$ could be, but this isn't enough to pin down $[2x]$.  It turns out that $2x$ can only be in a certain part of that interval, but the approach you are taking isn't enough to show that.
Let us write $x=n+f$ where $n\in \mathbb Z$ and $f\in [0,1)$.  Then $2x=2n+2f$ and so $[2x]=2n+[2f]$.  But $[2f]=0$ if $f<1/2$ and $[2f]=1$ if $f\geq 1/2$.  The same is true of $[f+1/2]$, and since $[2f]=[f+1/2]$ we have $$[2x]=2n+[2f]=2n+[f+1/2]=n+(n+[f+1/2])=[x]+[x+1/2].$$

I already see two provided answers, but I'll give a more general approach.
Let's prove that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have: $\lfloor nx\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{1}{n}\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor x+\frac{n-1}{n}\rfloor$. Note that your problem follows from this one if $n=2$.
Suppose $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed and let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=\lfloor nx\rfloor-\lfloor x\rfloor-\lfloor x+\frac{1}{n}\rfloor-\dots-\lfloor x-\frac{n-1}{n}\rfloor$.
It is easy to check that $f(x+\frac{1}{n})=f(x)$ (you just need to use the property that $\lfloor x+k \rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$). Therefore, we just need to study the function $f(x)$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{n})$.
But notice that if $x\in [0,\frac{1}{n})$, then $\lfloor nx\rfloor=0$ and for every $k\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$, we have $$0\leq x\leq x+\frac{k}{n}\leq x+\frac{n-1}{n}<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}=1$$ and hence $\lfloor x+\frac{k}{n}\rfloor=0$. Therefore $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{n})$ and by periodicity $f(x)\equiv 0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
